# Android JavascriptInterface use context to call method in activity (OOP)

Tags: android, oop

In `OOP`, I can use the object to call its methods. So I want to do that in android using the same concept. However, it doesn't work. I used `context` to call the function `updateLvl(int)`, but it said the method cannot be resolved. I want to know how can I use the `context` to call the method `updateLvl`?

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private WebView webview;
SharedPreferences sharedPref;
SharedPreferences.Editor editor;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


    sharedPref = this.getPreferences(0);
    editor = sharedPref.edit();

    webview = new WebView(this);
    webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webview.addJavascriptInterface(new WebViewJavaScriptInterface2(this), "app");


public void updateLvl(int newLvl){
    sharedPref = this.getPreferences(0);
    editor = sharedPref.edit();
    int be4Level = sharedPref.getInt("currLevel", 1);
    if (newLvl >= be4Level){
        editor.putInt("currLevel", newLvl);
        editor.commit();
    }
  }


}

class WebViewJavaScriptInterface2{

private Context context;
/*
 * Need a reference to the context in order to sent a post message
 */
public WebViewJavaScriptInterface2(Context context){
    this.context = context;
}

@JavascriptInterface
public void openLvl(int lvl){
    context.updateLvl(lvl);
}

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you need to cast your `context` as `MainActivity` because your `MainActivity` class has `updateLvl` method not `Context` class hence compiler will show you error while applying static binding

```
@JavascriptInterface
public void openLvl(int lvl){
    if(context instanceof MainActivity) // add safety check if required
        ((MainActivity)context).updateLvl(lvl);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `Context` is not the instance of your `WebViewJavaScriptInterface2` but a class of the android system (as well as Activity).

One way is to cast the context to the activity as Pavneet suggested. But this has the flaw that you can not be absolutely sure in your WebViewJavaScriptInterface2 that is is instanced from the right activity. Also you can use it just from one activity if you cast it to that one.

A cleaner way would be to define a callback interface, implement that interface in your activity (or multiple activity) and pass that callback interface into the `WebViewJavaScriptInterface2`.

Answer (score 0):

This might help someone.

```
new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper())
  .post(new Runnable(){
    @override
    public void run(){
      updateLvl(lvl);
    }
  });
```